# how to input value into field by using buttons? (html, js calculator)

Tags: javascript, html, css

We've just started to learn Vanilla JS, we had exercise which is creating a calculator by using html, css and js.

I already created the calculator layout (I'll leave the CSS to the end), however I'm getting troubled of input the number that I want into field by using the buttons.

Basically this is my layout so far, but I have some questions about the calculator that I want.

Before I'll show you the layout, here is how I want the calculator looks like by looking at the fields:
[image: field layout exampple]

So as you can see, in field 1 I want to input the first value,
now that we entered the first value, I want to show the math action that I want to do between the 2 values, in field 3 I want to input the second value,
after I inputted the value, I'll press on the equal button, the the last field will show me the result..

As I said before, I already created the layout for both fields and buttons, here is the layout:

```
<div class="calculator">

    <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="1" disabled /> <!--value 1-->
    <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="math action" disabled /> <!--math action-->
    <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="2" disabled /> <!--value 2-->
    
    <button type="button" class="equal-sign" value="=" onclick="solve()">=</button>
    <input type="text" class="result" value="result" disabled />
  
    <div class="calculator-keys">
  
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="+" onclick="dis('+')">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="-" onclick="dis('-')">-</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="*" onclick="dis('*')">*</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="/" onclick="dis('/')">/</button> <br>
  
      <button type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')">7</button>
      <button type="button" value="8" onclick="dis('8')">8</button>
      <button type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('8')">9</button><br>
  
  
      <button type="button" value="4" onclick="dis('4')">4</button>
      <button type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')">5</button>
      <button type="button" value="6" onclick="dis('6')">6</button><br>
  
  
      <button type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')">1</button>
      <button type="button" value="2" onclick="dis('2')">2</button>
      <button type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')">3</button><br>
  
  
      <button type="button" value="0" onclick="dis('0')">0</button>
      <button type="button" class="decimal" value="." onclick="dis('.')">.</button>
      <button type="button" class="all-clear" value="all-clear" onclick="clr()">AC</button>        
  </div>
```

and my js code so far:

```js
function dis(val) 
     { 
         document.getElementById("result").value+=val 
     } 
     
     //function that clear the display 
 function clr() 
     { 
         document.getElementById("result").value = "" 
     }
```

So after I did the layout and the buttons how do I make it that I'll be able to input the values by using the buttons?

in addition to that, how to I show the math action (- * / +) between the values field?

Comment: your `result` input have a class named `result` but you search it by id.. give to the input `id="result"`

Comment: what can i do for the rest of the this i mentioned ?
im getting troubled by applying the math action into its field
the the values

Answer (score 2):

The way I have solved this in the past is:

- Set a variable to keep track of **which operand** number we are working with, the
  first or second operand. Let's call this variable `thisOperand`. Set
  this variable to the `first` operand to begin with.
- When a number is input at any time, check the value of `thisOperand`. If `first` append the number (which you got from the `value` attribute) to the first operand field, if `second` to the second operand field.
- When the **operator** is chosen, if there is a first operand already
  entered (i.e. the display element is not empty), set `thisOperand`
  variable to value of `second`, so that the next numbers input are
  placed after the operator. Otherwise if there is no first operand
  entered don't do anything. If the second operand is already active,
  this means we've already entered an operator earlier - otherwise the
  second operand would not be active - so just update the operator with
  the new value.
- When the '=' button is pressed, show the result and set `thisOperand`
  to `first` again. If the result is shown and a new number is pressed,
  run the clear function and place the number in the first operand
  field (as a physical calculator would).

All this is easier if you set id attributes to refer to the display fields (the ones which have `value` attributes of '1', 'math action' and '2' in your example above).